# T-SQL Database Restore Gives different Result to using SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am currently trying to use T-SQL to restore my database using the following code:

```
RESTORE DATABASE database_name
FROM DISK = 'D:\Backup\database_name.bak'
WITH 
   MOVE 'dandenong' TO 'C:\Users\alans\Desktop\Database Files\database_name.mdf', 
   MOVE 'dandenong_log' TO 'C:\Users\alans\Desktop\Database Files\database_name.ldf',
GO
```

This works, however, it restores it to the 4th of April which was the second last backup it had.

However, when I SSMS and restore the database, it restores it to the latest backup time which is what I want.

How do I get the T-SQL statement to do the same?

Comment: In the Restore dialog box, go for the script option and see what script is being generated to compare your script against generated script

Answer (score 1):

You can find your backup information through the following script and then you can restore the proper backup file which you want.

```
SELECT  physical_device_name 
FROM msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily 
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset ON msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.media_set_id = msdb.dbo.backupset.media_set_id 
WHERE (CONVERT(datetime, msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_start_date, 102) >= GETDATE() - 7) 
AND msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name ='database_name'
ORDER BY 
msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget that **BACKUP FILES are virtual disks** and in a disk you can put more than one BACKUPS.
By Default BACKUP to a file when existing, appends the new backup into the file.
I think you can see the mater in executing the following command :

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'D:\Backup\database_name.bak'
```

So when you are restoring with this command :

```
RESTORE DATABASE database_name
FROM DISK = 'D:\Backup\database_name.bak'
WITH 
   MOVE 'dandenong' TO 'C:\Users\alans\Desktop\Database Files\database_name.mdf', 
   MOVE 'dandenong_log' TO 'C:\Users\alans\Desktop\Database Files\database_name.ldf'
GO
```

You just restore to the first oldest backup, wich is equivalent to this command :

```
RESTORE DATABASE database_name
FROM DISK = 'D:\Backup\database_name.bak'
WITH 
   MOVE 'dandenong' TO 'C:\Users\alans\Desktop\Database Files\database_name.mdf', 
   MOVE 'dandenong_log' TO 'C:\Users\alans\Desktop\Database Files\database_name.ldf'
WITH FILE = 1
GO
```

By using SSMS the assistant try to get the lastest database backup and surely do this command :

```
RESTORE DATABASE database_name
FROM DISK = 'D:\Backup\database_name.bak'
WITH 
   MOVE 'dandenong' TO 'C:\Users\alans\Desktop\Database Files\database_name.mdf', 
   MOVE 'dandenong_log' TO 'C:\Users\alans\Desktop\Database Files\database_name.ldf'
WITH FILE = 2
GO
```

You can have a look to the script that the SSMS assistant will throw before executing, that I recommand always !